# Why are Boost.Range range_begin/end free functions overloaded for both const as well as non-const references?

Tags: c++, boost, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup, boost-range

I found this interesting bit in [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html):

When providing [free-standing functions `range_begin/end()`, the docs state that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html):

> ... `range_begin()` and `range_end()` must be overloaded for both `const`
>   and `mutable` reference arguments.

And indeed, looking at their defaults in [`end.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/range/blob/master/include/boost/range/end.hpp), we see:

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // pair
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template< typename Iterator >
    inline Iterator range_end( const std::pair<Iterator,Iterator>& p )
    {
        return p.second;
    }

    template< typename Iterator >
    inline Iterator range_end( std::pair<Iterator,Iterator>& p )
    {
        return p.second;
    }
```

You will note (and the [example given in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html) also does this) that both versions return the same `Iterator` type.

**Why do we need both overload in the first place?** Is it to make [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously need the `const &` version because otherwise your `range_begin` would be uncallable for const-qualified objects.

Less obvious is why you also need the `&` version, but it's simple: if you don't provide it, then your custom function is a worse match than Boost's own version.

Here's a short non-Boost example:

```
namespace M {
  struct S { };
  void f(const S &);
}

namespace N {
  template <typename T>
  void f(T &);

  template <typename T>
  void g(T &t) { f(t); }
}

void h() {
  M::S s {};
  N::g(s);
}
```

Here, during instantiation of `N::g<M::S>`, an unqualified call `f(t)` is made, and the argument `t` has type `M::S`. There are two candidates: `N::f<M::S>` is in the same namespace, but ADL also finds `M::f`. The former's parameter is `M::S &`. The latter's is `const M::S &`. That means the former is a better match, even if you really want the version in namespace `M` to be used.

An additional overload `M::f(S &)` avoids this problem.

Comment: In your example, `M::f` is a non-template function. Does this make any difference (here)?

Comment: @MartinBa So long as `M::f` has both `S &` and `const S &` versions, it should work. For that, it doesn't matter whether those overloads are made available by a template.